# Issue with gensim.models.Phrases

Tags: python, nlp, gensim

```
from gensim.parsing import PorterStemmer
from gensim.models import Word2Vec, Phrases

class SentenceClass(object):
    def __init__(self, dirname):
        self.dirname = dirname

    def __iter__(self):
        for fname in os.listdir(self.dirname):
            with open(os.path.join(self.dirname,fname), 'r') as myfile:
                doc = myfile.read().replace('\n', ' ')
                for sent in tokenize.sent_tokenize(doc.lower()):
                    yield [Stemming.stem(word)\
                    for word in word_tokenize(re.sub("[^A-Za-z]", " ",sent))\
                    if word not in stopwords]
```

Now of the two approaches:
1)

```
model = Word2Vec(SentenceClass(data_dir_path), size=100, window=5, min_count=1, workers=4)
```

The above one runs really fine with no warning

2)

```
bigram_transformer = Phrases(SentenceClass(data_dir_path), min_count=1)
model = Word2Vec(bigram_transformer[SentenceClass(data_dir_path)], size=100, window=5, min_count=1, workers=4)
```

produces the warning:

```
WARNING:gensim.models.word2vec:train() called with an empty iterator (if not intended, be sure to provide a corpus that offers restartable iteration = an iterable).
WARNING:gensim.models.word2vec:supplied example count (0) did not equal expected count (30)
```

Now I do understand the difference between generator and iterators, and I am passing iterators, which is verified by printing below commands multiple times:

```
print(list(SentenceClass(data_dir_path)))
print(list(SentenceClass(data_dir_path)))
print(list(bigram_transformer[SentenceClass(data_dir_path)]))
print(list(bigram_transformer[SentenceClass(data_dir_path)]))
```

And it prints thing fine, but I am still not sure why the warning of "empty iterator" for the second case, am I missing something here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realised that Phrases & phrases are both making a generator only and the following class was required

```
from gensim.models import Word2Vec, Phrases, phrases

class PhraseItertor(object):

    def __init__(self, my_phraser, data):
        self.my_phraser, self.data = my_phraser, data

    def __iter__(self):
        return self.my_phraser[self.data]

my_sentences = SentenceClass(data_dir_path)
my_phrases = Phrases(my_sentences, min_count=1)
bigram = phrases.Phraser(my_phrases)
my_corpus = PhraseItertor(bigram,my_sentences)

model = Word2Vec(my_corpus, size=100, window=5, min_count=1, workers=4)
```